# Reading a number from a file and converting it to an integer in C

Tags: c, file, atoi

I have a `FILE` variable, declared as `FILE *fin`.  `fin = fopen( "points.dat", "r" );` is initialized after the declaration.  I've been trying to loop through `fin` while `fgetc( fin ) != '\n'`.  Here's where I am stumped.

I want to store each character on line 1 of `points.dat` into a `char *`, which I can later invoke `atoi` on to store as an integer.  How should I do this?  I've tried it, but I keep getting segmentation faults and other weird errors.  Here's my latest attempt:

```
FILE *fin;
char c;
int counter = 0;
int countPoints;
char *readFirst;

fin = fopen( "points.dat", "r" );

while( ( c = fgetc( fin ) ) != '\n' ) {

    readFirst[counter] = c;
    counter++;
}

countPoints = atoi( readFirst );

printf("%d\n", countPoints);
```

Note: this is not in its entirity a homework assignment.  This is just a very small thing I need to get working before I can actually do the homework assignment.

Comment: Use `'\n'` instead of `10` for the sake of readability.

Comment: declaring a `char*` doesn't actually reserve any memory for those characters you want to store.  Look up `malloc()`

Comment: Memory for readFirst needs to be allocated using malloc. That is the reason you are getting a seg fault.

Comment: Is it just me or have there been a lot of `atoi` questions lately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a segmentation fault because `char *readFirst;` only declares a pointer, but it doesn't reserve any space to hold the data.

Either declare `readFirst` directly as an array (`char readFirst[size];`) or use the function `malloc()` to allocate the space.

Comment: So will I have to loop through once, find out `size`, close the file, re-open the file, read the characters in **again**, *then* assign them to `char *readFirst`?

Comment: If you can't estimate the length of the first line, soft of. You can rewind a file using `rewind()`. No need to reopen. But if you know beforehand that the first line won't be longer than 500 bytes, just use `char readFirst[500];`.

Answer (score 2):

You have not allocated any memory to readFirst and also it is not terminated with NULL character as C expects.

Its better to use fgets to read a string and fputs to write the string. That way you dont have to look for the newline.
Also, it will be useful if you post the code of writing to file.

You could also use standard c++ file handling (using std::iostream), to make the job even easier.

Comment: I'm not writing anything to a file - just reading from a file.  But I will look into `fgets`.

Comment: Also make sure to allocate memory to pointer by either using malloc or array.

Answer (score 0):

readFirst is an uninitialized char pointer.  You either need to alloc a new block of memory to hold the characters or assign it to a statically allocated array of chars.   Also, if you are going to read the data a single byte at a time, you will need to null terminate the string before passing it into atoi or it will read passed the end of the buffer and segfault as well.

See if you can figure it out from there.  If you need more help, message me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the immediate problem is that you haven't set aside any memory for `readFirst` to point *to*.  When you write `readFirst[counter] = c`, you're trying to assign the value of `c` to some random memory location that you may or may not own (hence the segfaults).

If you know how big the array needs to be ahead of time, you should declare `readFirst` as

```
char readFirst[SIZE];
```

It takes roughly 3.3 bits on average to represent a decimal digit; round that down to 3, and you can figure your array size as the bit width of an `int` divided by 3 plus 2 for the sign and 0 terminator.  Thus, a 32 bit int will require an array of 9 + 2 = 11 characters.  A 64-bit integer value will require 22 + 2 = 24.

But this all begs another question; do you *need* to read the input one character at a time and then convert to an integer value?  If the input file is simply text representations of integers, you could bypass that whole mess and simply use `fscanf` with the `%d` conversion specifier (although that has its own set of issues).

Alternately, you could use `fgets` to read an entire text string at once and convert the text using `strtol` (`atoi` doesn't give you the same error handling capability as `strtol`).

Answer (score 0):

When I see this right, you just use your `char` pointer without initializing it to something. That means your pointer points to some unknown memory area. If you are lucky you get a segmentation fault (that's why initializing a pointer to `NULL` is a good idea), if not: Welcome in the realm of undefinedness.

If you want to store something you should first create some memory for it. You can do that either on the stack (`char readFirst[size]`) or on the heap (`malloc()`). In every case you need to know beforehand how much memory you will be needing. You need to know this at compile time for the stack variant and at run time for the heap variant. That of course means that you need a method to find out how much memory you will be needing.